# paypal REST api: shipping_address does not understand utf8 characters

Tags: node.js, utf-8, paypal

I'm requesting out of a node application via the [nodejs sdk](https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-nodejs):

```
paypal.payment.create({ ... }, function (err, transaction) {
    fn(err, transaction);
});
```

The `shipping_address` payload looks like this:

```
{ 
  recipient_name : 'Max Mustermann',
  line1          : 'Neue Schönhauser Str 18', // the 'ö' causes error
  line2          : 'Vorderhaus, links',
  city           : 'Berlin',
  country_code   : 'DE',
  postal_code    : '10178',
  state          : 'BE',
  type           : 'residential' 
}
```

The utf-8 character in `line1` key's value causes a `MALFORMED_REQUEST` error. If I replace it by `oe` everything works fine.

Does paypal's REST api understand utf-8?
Do I have to setup the character encoding somewhere?

Thx

Answer (score 1):

Issue was due to incorrect Content-Length getting set from the nodejs sdk and not the API.  We have fixed the SDK and published the latest version to npm. Please use 0.6.4 version which has the fix for the same. Thanks for reporting.

Answer (score 0):

It should accept this, yes, of course.  Let me check this for you as it shouldn't throw an error on that.